# Invoke android application from browser

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

I have been trying to invoke my application from browser on **android 3.1 (Honeycomb)** 
These are the links I tried, but none of these worked:

```
<a href="com.nk.myapp://movieid=95319">click me 1</a>

<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.nk.myapp.detail;end">click me 2</a>

<a href=intent:#Intent;action=com.nk.myapp.detail;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;package=com.nk.myapp;end>click me 3</a>
```

For 1st and 2nd url, it gives "Webpage not available".

For 3rd one, it shows Apps-market with search: pname:com.nk.myapp --> "No Result found".

Application is still in development, so its not in the market yet.

This is how my manifest file looks like:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.nk.myapp.action.DIALOG" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".WebViewActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="com.nk.myapp" />
        <action android:name="com.nk.myapp.detail" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Let me know if you find what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is Another way to do it:

To find out uri, this is what I added in Test Apk:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.appname.NK_CUSTOM_ACTION");
i.putExtra("movie_id", "123456");
Log.e("IntentTest", i.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
```

Which produces this string:

```
intent:#Intent;action=com.appname.NK_CUSTOM_ACTION;S.movie_id=123456;end
```

Html page has this link:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.appname.NK_CUSTOM_ACTION;S.movie_id=123456;end">click to load</a>
```

And, change manifest file to

```
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.appname.NK_CUSTOM_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In TestActivity, you get movie_id in code below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("movie_id");
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of i.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)

Comment: Thank you, NASA. Thank you, NASA! Thank you, NASA!! Thank you, NASA!!! This is the most valuable page I've met in SO in the last year. NiTiN, you've helped me out of a very deep hole. Most obliged.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem while ago, just in case anyone needs it:

This is how my html page looks like (which get downloaded from browser on device):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Andriod Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
            if (default_ == null) default_ = "";
            key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
            var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (qs == null)
                return default_;
            else
                return qs[1];
        }

        function invokeApp(xyz) {
            var id = getQuerystring('id');
            var contentType = getQuerystring('contentType');
            var url = "myAppSceme://movie?id=" + id ;    
            document.getElementById('ref').href = url;                
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="#" id="ref" onclick="invokeApp(this);" >click me!</a>  

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Manifest file looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".DetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
  <intent-filter >
    <data android:scheme="myAppSceme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code in DetailActivity:

```
String id = getIntent().getDataString().replace("myAppSceme://movie?id=", "");
```