# How to force email validation to open in webview android

Tags: javascript, php, android, css, webview

I have a friend who created an online betting game. Now, in order to deploy it on mobile, I just created a webview to display the website. First, you have to register. After registration on my phone, I opened my Gmail. I clicked the Email Validation Link, but instead of opening the webpage on the Webview, the browser opened. We are trying to test it. I hope someone with knowledge in php,javascript,css or ajax. Please help Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the webview is hosted in a thin app you made, and you'd like the email verification link to open up inside that app.

In that case, on Android, the way you do this is with Intents ([wiki overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intent_%28Android%29), [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html), [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)).

You would have to mark up the link in the email with a special scheme that Android would interpret to mean "Open up my thin app with these parameters."  So, rather than:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/verify=adfasdfadsfadsf">Verify Email</a>
```

You would have

```
<a href="myGameScheme://params?verify=asdfadfadf">Verify Email</a>
```

Here is a related StackOverflow question to follow up with (they use JavaScript instead of a proper href -- you'll have to test): [Invoke android application from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480559/invoke-android-application-from-browser)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need override WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading() having it return false (please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String))and set the WebViewClient on your WebView (please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient))